# How to analyse RAM usage in depth?

Tags: 18.04, ram, memory-usage

Please advise, given the following server RAM usage:

[image]

Who uses these 12.4G?
I have used free, top but no one shows me who uses this amount of memory.
Please advise how can I analyse it in depth.

Comment: It looks like Chrome is doing what chrome does... How many chrome processes are there from `ps awux | grep -v grep | grep chrome | wc -l`? Around 24? Multiply that by usage...

Comment: @SHawarden but it doesn't use 12G, I believe it can use 5G but not that much

Comment: @SHawarden 106 processes

Comment: `ps -axo rss,fname | grep chrome | awk '{print $2,$1;sum+=$1} END{print "TOTAL: "sum/1024/1024}'` should show you how much resident memory chrome is using. There may well be other things using memory though. 106 chrome processes though. A lot of them are in the half GB range. 24 of those will give you 12G